# How do I use fstream to read & conserve '\n' as a char when it changes to a new line in a .txt file?

Tags: c++, char, fstream

Let's say the .txt file has two lines as follows:

```
Hi, X
Bye
```

I want the vector to contain `['H', 'i', ',', ' ', 'X', '\n', 'B', 'y', 'e']`, but I can't manage to get `fstream` to record `'\n'` as a char (it just makes it a `' '` aka whitespace).

Any ideas? Am I using the wrong methodology for the answer I want?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<char> text;
    char c;
    fstream inputFile;
    string filePath = "C:\\doc\\lib\\hello.txt";
    inputFile.open(filePath);
    inputFile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);

    if(!inputFile) exit(1);

    while(inputFile >> c){
        text.push_back(c);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++){
        cout << text[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `include ...` should be `#include ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams distinguish between "formatted" reads, and "unformatted" reads.

- [Formatted reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) will always skip whitespace

  - `operator>>`
- [Unformatted reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction) will read all bytes.

  - All of the member functions, including `.getline`
  - `std::getline`
  - `std::ws`
  - `basic_istream::operator>>(basic_streambuf*)`

So, if you want to read in whitespace characters, simply use anything besides `operator>>`.

In your case, it appears you want `inputFile.get()`, though there are more efficient ways to read the input.

Note that both `getline` methods will skip over but not return the delimiter, which defaults to `'\n'`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I will read the documentation and try the unformatted read method :)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel They both read all bytes until the delimiter, including newlines, and then skip the delimiater. The only thing that makes them "different" is that the default delimiter is the newline character. I can note it though.

Comment: @Capacitor In this situation, you should be using `istream::get()` to read each char individually, and which will not ignore whitespace chars (as `operator>>` does), eg: `while (inputFile.get(c)){ ... }`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Picky picky :P Clarified.

Comment: I was about to say this didn't work, but then I face palmed and realised I was trying to verify the script using operator>> for outputting the vector's contents. This works now. Thank you guys, I really appreciate the help!